# SELECT rows WHERE NOT EXISTS condition from 2 tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, razor

I have 2 `tables`, named `SectionAccess` and `AdminConsole` respectively. SectionAccess contains the fields

```
 - User Access
 - User ID
 - Link.
```

1 User ID can have a few Links. 
`AdminConsole` has the fields

```
 - Link
 - Project ID (PPMID)
 - Application ID (EPRID)
 - Project Name.
```

Each Link has a unique Project.

I'm creating a `webpage` using `Razor` where the user can key in his User ID, and the webpage will show the projects that are currently under that User ID in a table. The SQL query I did for that is:

```
SELECT SectionAccess.Link, SectionAccess.UserID, AdminConsole.PPMID, AdminConsole.EPRID, AdminConsole.Proj_Name FROM SectionAccess 
INNER JOIN AdminConsole ON SectionAccess.Link=AdminConsole.Link 
WHERE SectionAccess.UserID like ('%" + Request["UserID"] + "%');
```

This works great. Now I'm adding another table below this table that will display the projects that are NOT tied to that User ID. I did this, but it doesn't return anything.

```
SELECT Link, PPMID, EPRID, Proj_Name FROM AdminConsole
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT SectionAccess.Link, SectionAccess.UserID, AdminConsole.PPMID, AdminConsole.EPRID, AdminConsole.Proj_Name FROM SectionAccess 
INNER JOIN AdminConsole ON SectionAccess.Link=AdminConsole.Link 
WHERE SectionAccess.UserID = '" + Request["UserID"] + "');
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining **AdminConsole** again within your subquery, while it should be  filtered by **AdminConsole** from your main query.

Your query does not request what you want:

```
SELECT Link, PPMID, EPRID, Proj_Name FROM AdminConsole
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT SectionAccess.Link, SectionAccess.UserID, AdminConsole.PPMID, AdminConsole.EPRID, AdminConsole.Proj_Name FROM SectionAccess 
INNER JOIN AdminConsole ON SectionAccess.Link=AdminConsole.Link 
WHERE SectionAccess.UserID = '" + Request["UserID"] + "');
```

Your subquery does deliver rows, if the user has at least one project. Therefore not exists is false and you will get no rows from **AdminConsole** in this case.

You have to filter your subquery by your main querys **AdminConsole.Link**. Something like:

```
SELECT Link, PPMID, EPRID, Proj_Name FROM AdminConsole
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT SectionAccess.Link, SectionAccess.UserID FROM SectionAccess 
WHERE SectionAccess.UserID = '" + Request["UserID"] + "' and
   SectionAccess.Link=AdminConsole.Link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to leave out the join in the subquery:

```
SELECT Link, PPMID, EPRID, Proj_Name FROM AdminConsole
WHERE Link NOT IN 
(SELECT SectionAccess.Link FROM SectionAccess 
WHERE SectionAccess.UserID = '" + Request["UserID"] + "');
```

Answer (score 0):

Exists cannot return NULL. It’s checking solely for the presence or absence of a row in the subquery and, hence, it can only return true or false.

You can use EXCEPT

SELECT SectionAccess.Link, SectionAccess.UserID, AdminConsole.PPMID, AdminConsole.EPRID, AdminConsole.Proj_Name FROM SectionAccess 
INNER JOIN AdminConsole ON SectionAccess.Link=AdminConsole.Link

EXCEPT

SELECT SectionAccess.Link, SectionAccess.UserID, AdminConsole.PPMID, AdminConsole.EPRID, AdminConsole.Proj_Name FROM SectionAccess 
INNER JOIN AdminConsole ON SectionAccess.Link=AdminConsole.Link 
WHERE SectionAccess.UserID like ('%" + Request["UserID"] + "%');